# how can I find the lowest value of each row and exclude them to find a new average from array

Tags: java, arrays, average

I'm having trouble getting the output to match the given output. I have the structure made but finding little discrepancies with my output.

```
public void printStudentsAvgWithoutLowest() {
        //do not declare variable here
        double average = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrScores.length; i++) {
             double lowest = 100;      //CHANGE HERE 
            for (int j = 0; j < arrScores[i].length; j++) {
                if (arrScores[i].length < lowest) {
                    lowest = arrScores[i][j];
                }
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < arrScores[i].length; k++) {
                if (arrScores[i][k] != lowest) {
                    average = average + arrScores[i][k];
                }
            }
            average = average / (arrScores[i].length - 1);
            System.out.printf("Student#%s Average (without lowest score): %.2f\n", i, average);
            average = 0;
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
```

this is the array I have made using txt file given.

```
100.00     90.00    100.00     80.00     70.00
50.00     60.00     70.00     80.00    100.00
60.00     70.00    100.00     80.00     90.00
69.50     70.50     80.50     30.50      0.00
78.30     69.50     48.00     90.00    100.00
88.50     95.00    100.00     99.00      0.00
```

I need to find the average of each row which excludes the lowest value.

my output is as follows:

```
Student#0 Average (without lowest score): 92.50
Student#1 Average (without lowest score): 65.00
Student#2 Average (without lowest score): 77.50
Student#3 Average (without lowest score): 62.75
Student#4 Average (without lowest score): 96.45
Student#5 Average (without lowest score): 95.63
```

sample output given:

```
Student#0 Average (without lowest score): 92.50
Student#1 Average (without lowest score): 77.50
Student#2 Average (without lowest score): 85.00
Student#3 Average (without lowest score): 62.75
Student#4 Average (without lowest score): 84.45
Student#5 Average (without lowest score): 95.63
```

Student# 1, 2, and 4 have different outputs given from the sample output.

Comment: You need to reset `lowest` to 100 at the start or end of the for loop, otherwise, it keeps the lowest value from the previous iteration of the loop. Just add `lowest = 100;` after `for (int i = 0; i < arrScores.length; i++) {`. Also, be warned that your code will give incorrect values if you have two or more identical lowest scores.

Comment: Defining the variable in the for loop helped as well, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each row can have a different lowest value, so you should define the variable inside the loop. (Additionally, although it does not come up in your current input, you might want to consider the case where the lowest value occurs multiple times. To solve that, you could sum all the array values while finding the minimum value, then subtract that minimum value from the computed sum before dividing.)

```java
double lowest = Double.MAX_VALUE;
for (int j = 0; j < arrScores[i].length; j++) {
    lowest = Math.min(lowest, arrScores[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: defining the variable inside the for loop helped, thank you so much. appreciate you, things like these is something I tend to overlook.